# Spring MVC: Update an existing entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

Entity class

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;
    private String country;
    private String state;
    private String roles;
    private String permissions;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=6)
    private String password;
    private String telNumber;


    public User() {
    }
    public User(String firstName,String lastName,String email,String roles,String permissions,String password) {
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
    this.email=email;
    this.roles=roles;
    this.permissions=permissions;
    this.password=password;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country= country;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setMesto(String state) {
        this.state= state;
    }
    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public List<String> getRolesList(){
        if(this.roles.length()>0){
            return Arrays.asList(this.roles.split(","));
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public List<String> getPermissionsLisst(){
        if(this.permissions.length()>0){
            return Arrays.asList(this.permissions.split(","));
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }


    public void setPermissions(String permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getTelNumber() {
        return telNumber;
    }

    public void setTelNumber(String telNumber) {
        this.telNumber = telNumber;
    }
```

This is my view

```
    <div class="udaje container mx-auto text-dark">
<form th:action="@{/admin/useractions}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName" class="form-control-label">First Name</label> <input
            type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{firstName}" id="firstName" />
        <div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}"
             th:errors="*{firstName}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName" class="form-control-label">Last Name</label> <input
            type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{lastName}" id="lastName" />
        <div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}"
             th:errors="*{lastName}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="form-control-label">Email</label> <input
            type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" id="email" />
        <div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}"
             th:errors="*{email}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label">State</label><input
            type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{state}" id="state" />
        <div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('state')}"
             th:errors="*{state}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country" class="form-control-label">Country</label> <input
            type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{mesto}" id="country" />
        <div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('country')}"
             th:errors="*{country}"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="form-control-label">Password</label> <input
            type="password" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}" id="password" />
        <div class="text text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}"
             th:errors="*{password}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark" />
    </div>

</form>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserServices userServices;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    public int roh;
    @GetMapping("/admin/userlist")
    public String userList(Model model,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String email){
        model.addAttribute("users",userServices.findByEmailLike(email));
        return "/admin/userlist";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/admin/useractions")
    public String userActions(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Integer id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user",userServices.findOne(id));
        return "/admin/useractions";
    }
@PutMapping("/admin/useractions")
public User updateUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    return userServices.update(user);
}
```

}

Hello im looking for method to update user with jpa repository..
I ve tried many ways, i browsed trough internet in 1/2 cases it was recieving error id is not present( like with this one way

```
public User update(User user){
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

), 
or it was not updating user, but creating a new one.. 
Also im using PasswordEncoder, and when i want to print user password in password field it is just empty, is it possible to type *** like password in field?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code has various errors and misunderstandings:

Change it to be something like:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserServices userServices;

    @GetMapping("/admin/userlist")
    public String userList(Model model,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String email){
        model.addAttribute("users",userServices.findByEmailLike(email));
        return "/admin/userlist";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin/useractions")
    public String userActions(){
        return "/admin/useractions";
    }

    @PostMapping("/admin/useractions")
    public String updateUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userServices.update(user);

        return "/theNextView";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User getUser(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Integer id) {
        return id !=null ? userServices.findOne(id) : new User();
    }
}
```

and in your edit form add:

`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${user.id}" />`

on both GET and POST `getUser(...)` will populate the model with an existing user if the requestParam `id` is set as an URL param or a hidden field.

In the latter case, this existing user will be passed to the POST handler and the submitted form data will be bound to this existing instance.

Comment: And im also wondering how to type ****** in password field with password value?

Answer (score 1):

It's creating new one, not updating, because you are not sending `id` of user from the form. Repository checks, behind the scene, if the id is there is uses the id to update the record, otherwise it creates a new record.

Just send the id as hidden field from the view, then it should update the record.

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="${id}" />
```

Comment: where to put it?

Comment: Curently i have it as is upper and i got this error parameter 'id' is not present|400